# I reseeded my lawn but the results are patchy. Do I apply further seed, or start again?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I had a tree taken down and the stump ground up.  I cleared a majority of the tree mulch and laid top soil, seeded, and put some hay on top.  It's been a couple of weeks and the grass is growing in really patchy.  It looks pretty bad.  It's been extremely hot lately, so I'm thinking it's probably not getting enough water.

My question is: should I rake up the hay, dig up what's currently there, and start from scratch?  Or should I seed on top of the existing patchy grass?  (I'll be sure to water more often this time around.)

Comment: @Rob Sobers, do you have a cool-season or a warm-season lawn? I would guess a cool-season lawn since you're seeding, but that is no guarantee...

Comment: @Mike I believe I have a cool-season lawn (I live in the northeast)

Comment: seeing as you're that far North [New York, NY](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/596/rob-sobers) I agree. It would be highly unlikely to have a warm-season that far North... ["aphoria" answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/i-reseeded-my-lawn-but-the-results-are-patchy-do-i-apply-further-seed-or-start/1547#1547) is a good one (IMHO). Personally, I believe now through Sept is the perfect time to reseed a cool-season lawn. Instead of straw, I use a ½inch (12.5mm) thick layer of compost to cover the seed...

Comment: additionally you may find [my lawn care procedure](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-an-organic-way-to-discourage-crabgrass-from-a-large-lawn/1391#1391) worth a read...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would continue to water it, but not do anything else until you get cooler weather.

Then, in the fall or spring...

- Rake it a bit to loosen the soil
- Put down more seed
- Cover with straw, but not too thick
- Water

Answer (score 11):

If it's just starting to grow and coming in patchy, just give it time.  It will probably fill in. If after two months it's still offensively patchy, sprinkle more grass seed on the patchy bits.

Comment: +1. Loosen up the bare dirt too, if it's become compacted and hard in the meantime.

Comment: Scott's EZ Seed is also great stuff

Answer (score 7):

If you only seeded your lawn, it could also be that the local wildlife (aka birds) have come in and swiped some of your seeds, despite the hay.

Another option you could try, along with the seeding, is to take small "plugs" from other parts of the yard and plant them in the spot you're trying to grow. This has the benefit of taking established grass with roots and putting it in a new spot. The spot where you took the plug from will regrow from the neighbouring lawn.

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to add compost and some grass starter fertilizer.

Also during the first few weeks grass is very sensitive so you need to water a little very often.

During hot days that may be 10 - 15 minutes up to 5 times a day.

An added bonus of compost is that it holds water better than regular topsoil.

Comment: +1 for compost. I just seeded a good large area this way, and am now praying for frequent showers!