# How can I mow a moist lawn?

Tags: lawn, lawn-mower, mowing

My lawn is wet at the moment (well, a bit dewey, not soaking as in just rained), and it clogs my mower, causing it to work harder and fail to collect anything in the basket.

Is there a solution besides waiting until dried? Walk faster/slower? Speed up or down my blades?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the recommendation is to wait until it is dry. As well as clogging problems, you can damage the grass - although this latter issue isn't a problem for a heterogeneous low quality "lawn" such as mine!

Raising the blades will reduce the amount of cuttings produced - so this will reduce clogging.

Also, have you considered leaving it on the lawn as mulch, rather than bagging? This should help but it will still have some clogging problems - the grass can build up between the blades and cover to eventually stall the motor.

Comment: Raising the blades did help, at least it's even again :) Also stopping a lot and cleaning/grabbing the clogs helps.. Summers ain't what they used to be!

Answer (score 10):

I've learnt to **never** cut my lawn when it's:

1. Damp, wet.
2. During dry, hot spells (generally July & August here in Missouri), when temperatures are constantly over 90°F (32°C).

Yes, my grass does on occasion get somewhat long, but never long enough for it to become an eyesore -- at least I don't believe so (and I'm not living in denial here, honest), nor have I had anyone complain to me directly or indirectly about it...

As you've discovered, cutting grass when it's damp (wet) is difficult, plus:

- You won't get a good cut. Period.
- The grass will mat-down, smother itself.
- You increase the possibility of fungal diseases taking hold in your lawn -- cut, wet blades are a lot more susceptible to allowing those kind of diseases to enter...
- You (greatly) increase the possibility of thatch buildup in your lawn, which it turn can lead to fungal diseases taking hold...

If you must mow your lawn when it's damp, wet, it is highly recommended you collect up the clippings as you go (via a bag attached to your mower). **Why?**

- Even a mulching type mower will not breakdown the clippings so they "disappear" into your lawn.
- The wet clippings will instead somewhat help mat-down your lawn and will most definitely add material to your lawns thatch layer.

If you wish to read about my "organic" approach to lawn care, [**go here**](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-an-organic-way-to-discourage-crabgrass-from-a-large-lawn/1391#1391) on SE.

Comment: Don't mow when it is over 90 degrees? I like that! Down here in Texas that would cut my mowing season down to 1-2 times/year. The grass might get a bit out of control though.